# Is it possible to use Wordpress as an online portfolio for text content? What kind of theme would I look for?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, themes, customization, plugin-recommendation

I'm trying to build an online portfolio for a quantity of text content I've produced. I don't have to skills to design it myself or the money to pay someone, so I thought using a CMS with a free theme might be a possible way to solve my problem.

Is it possible to use WP as a portfolio rather than a blog? (i.e. not have content appear date-stamped any in reverse chronological order?) If so, what kind of theme or other add-on would I look for?

I'm looking for someone really simple, but sleek and polished looking. I could just put a bunch of *.txt files on an ftp server, but I'm looking for something that looks just a little better and more professional, while still being free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use Pages inside WP. They differs from Post in the fact that are not chronological order and so doesn't present date-stamped. The order of appearance you define.

Comment: Indeed. WordPress is designed to accommodate a purely static-content site, and not just blogs. As for the question of what Theme to use: any Theme in the WPORG repository that has been updated in the last year or so should meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Simplefolio](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/07/simplefolio-a-free-clean-portfolio-wordpress-theme/) is a great option. (Note a [new version will be out soon](http://www.slimmity.com/))

Features:

- CSS-based layout
- 2 columns of fixed width
- XHTML 1.0 Transitional valid
- Multi-browser compatibility: tested on Firefox, Safari , IE7, IE8, Chrome
- Easy to setup, theme options page

Answer (score 0):

No need to select a specific theme,just use this plugin:
[Portfolio for WordPress](http://codecanyon.net/item/portfolio-for-wordpress/610791)

With this script you can easily manage your portfolio (images and videos) items on your website. Because this plugin uses a custom post type to manage your portfolio this is a very clean and powerfull way to build a portfolio into your website.

The visual part to style your portfolio items is not included in this plugin because most of the time there is already styling included in a theme for a portfolio.